# Subgroups of GL(E) realised as a stabilizer of a group action?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations, representation-theory, group-actions

I am being asked to define different subgroups of the general linear group as stabilizers of group actions on matrix spaces. As of now I have found these :

- The orthogonal group as a stabilizer of a quadratic form for the congruence action.
- The symplectic group as a stabiliser of a symplectic form for a similar action.
- The upper triangular matrices group as a stabilizer of a complete flag of vector subspaces for it's natural action.

> In this question, they talk about a decompostion with direct sums, but I am not sure : what subgroup would that bring?
>
> Do you have other examples of subgroups of GL(E) realised with group actions? (Either by a stabilizer or by other means).

I would be curious to find out about your examples. 
Perhaps representation theory can help here.

Comment: A trivial generalization of the orthogonal group $O(n)$ is $O(n, m)$, the Lorentz groups; the quadratic form is now $x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2-x_{n+1}^2-\ldots -x_{n+m}^2$.

Comment: In fact, by a theorem due to Chevalley, if you have any *algebraic* subgroup $H$ of $G=GL(V)$ (i.e. a subgroup given by a system of polynomial equations), then you can find a linear representation  of $G\to GL(W)$ such that $H$ is the stabilizer of a line in $W$.

Comment: @Kohan:  Thanks, now that certainly gives a broader perspective!

Comment: @Negro:  Yes O(n,m) is the stabiliser of the bloc diagonal matrix $diag(I_n, -I_m) $which is certainly an important quadratic form.